# Why does awaiting Selenium getAttribute still return a promise?

Tags: javascript, selenium, es6-promise

I am using Selenium for JavaScript and trying to create an array containing a form's input values. I know that `getAttribute` (as well as most other methods) return a Promise.  But, why are the values in the `values` array Promises even though I called `await`?

```
Then(/^The Author form should be empty$/, () => {
  return driver.findElements(By.css('.author-form input')).then( (inputs) => {
    expect(inputs.length).toBe(3)    
    let values = inputs.map(async (input) => await input.getAttribute('value'))
    console.log("The values")
    console.log(values)
    values.forEach((value) => {
      expect(value).toEqual('')
    })
  })
})
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
The values
[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
```

Doesn't calling `await` on `getAttribute` produce a value?

(Yes, I know the code looks a little strange.  I was trying to figure out how to call `expect` inside a `forEach` loop without getting an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` -- but that is a question for another post.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain why this is happening, let me provide another example:

```
let values = inputs.map(async (input) => {
    await input.getAttribute('value');
    console.log('After await');
});
```

Without async await, this becomes:

```
let values = inputs.map((input) => {
    return input.getAttribute('value').then((result) => {
        console.log('After await');
    });
});
```

You would expect in this case that values is a list of promises, which it is.

The problem you are running into is yes, you are awaiting the result. However an async function ALWAYS returns a promise. `map` does nothing to resolve that promise. The `await` inside the function passed to map doesn't actually do anything in this case. Instead, you need to do this:

```
const value_promises = inputs.map((input) => {
    return input.getAttribute('value');
});
const values = await Promise.all(value_promises);
```

`Promise.all` is designed for just this case, where you have a list of Promises and you want to get their values.